# Kotlin / Anko button onClick not working

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm fairly new to Kotlin, and I'm using Anko DSL (with some XML) to generate an alert. My issue is, the `onClick{ ... }` function doesn't happen when I click the button. Everything else works fine, it's just this one issue

```
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        alert {
            title = "Add Board"
            customView {
                include<View>(R.layout.alert_xml) {
                    this.spinner.adapter = adapter
                    info("Alert loaded")
                    val boardSpinner = this.spinner
                    val boardText = this.board_text
                    positiveButton("OK") {
                        onClick {
                            info("Testing")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda parameter that `positiveButton` takes is not a setup function, but the click listener itself, so you can write your code directly inside it:

```
positiveButton("OK") {
    info("Testing")
}
```

The `onClick` function that you're calling inside it is coming from another outer scope, and is overriding the listener of one of the outer views, presumably the listener for the root of the included view from the XML.